# How to verify Google's auth gapi.auth.signIn response?

Tags: javascript, authentication, oauth, google-oauth

I have a database with users and I want to let user to connect his website account with his google account. I want to be able to let user to log in with his google account too and maybe later to be able to interact with his google+ account etc.

User is logged in on the website and he initiates this process with a click on a button which does following:

```
// user initiates the process
$('#google-connect').on(function() {
    gapi.auth.signIn({
        'callback': function(data) {
        if(data['status']['signed_in'])
            console.log("Signed in", data, gapi.auth.getToken());

            // just get some additional user's data
            gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', function() {
                gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get().execute(function(resp) {
                    console.log("OAuth", resp);

                    data.userID = resp.id;

                    // tell server to add google account to user's account
                    $.post('/add/google', data, function(data) {
                        console.log("Connected", "data");
                    });
                });
            });
        },
        'clientid': GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        'cookiepolicy': 'single_host_origin',
        'requestvisibleactions': 'http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity',
        'approvalprompt':'force',
        'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
        //'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me'
    });
    return false;
});
// load libs
(function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script');
    po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
})();
```

it basicly works without problem but I am not sure is this secure and how to verify the answers form google server. For example, Facebook login returns "signedRequest" and I am able to run the verification with hash_hmac (php) to verify the response.

Google answers with this on my  gapi.auth.signIn() request:

```
access_token: "ya29.KgDiGDMeEpOEFxoAAAD2dV1eldwT_ZCcr-ODNR_LBKWbam7bOwZ0pplZ33hG3A"
authuser: "0"
client_id: "...."
code: "4/iqLG-akrpp_BGWGGx2b_RAqTSj29.AuyFPmgozMATOl05ti8ZT3bxU6v2jAI"
cookie_policy: "single_host_origin"
expires_at: "1402232030"
expires_in: "3600"
g-oauth-window: Window
g_user_cookie_policy: "single_host_origin"
id_token: "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjgxNDBjNWYxYzlkMGM3MzhjMWI2MzI4NTI4ZjdhYjFmNjcyZjViYTAifQ.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.Fil-uV6oFdeiRrO_vHFr5oVOnzVIfa2DvneDYaFF_eo3HOdOmD2wElD5UOjXxTLcNHtxyXg-zInyB9wDn1aQaZpYTSgG3Q-PN7oXcmUECyX5UJ7Aga0xgjAH6j57XBTx_BVdeiq1xLTPSMq9J2hZ1jGIkv-1qPedng7bRVGuRgQ"
issued_at: "1402228430"
num_sessions: "1"
prompt: "consent"
response_type: "code token id_token gsession"
scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.moments.write https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.agerange.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.language.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.members.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read"
session_state: "14f90adcf0c130936b1545ec15dbd8fe1515b4dc..0c9b"
state: ""
status: Object
token_type: "Bearer"
```

I did not find any information how to verify the response. There is no signature or something else except "id_token" which could be some kind of signature.

Is there a way to verify google's answer to be sure that information is correct, that there is no MITM? Or am I just worrying too much?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is :

Have you read [ID Token verification(PHP lib)](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/aaa_idtoken) ?

I guess, you could do the same in JavaScript using :

```
$.get("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo",{
    "id_token" : authResult["id_token"]},function(data){
    //Handle data...
});
```